# Check the history of uncommited changes

Tags: git

I made a changes for a file but didn't commit, and then I made a `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, is there anyway I can retrieve the content before the reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't commit it then you're probably out of luck as git will never have known anything about the changes. However, if you did commit but just didn't push then the reflog might be able to help. Luckily, I haven't needed it for a while but I think [this is the article](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html) I've used in the past.

Comment: git can only keep track of what it knows about, and the only things it knows about are the things that you commit. If you make frequent, small commits, you limit how much with you risk losing at any time.

Comment: Thanks, I'm rewriting the code now. Accidents happen anyway :)